# What is the best practise to secure data from back to front with archive

Tags: android, security, encryption, archive

I'm working on a project using android studio and moodle.

One of the objectives of the mission is to get data from moodle into an archive and get that archive into an SD card to access the data into the mobile without internet connexion.

The client wants the data on the SD card, not te be read by anyone.

So I thought of multiple solutions:

- Creating a key on the RAR archive
- Encrypting the archive
- Encrypting each file within the archive (and the archive ?)

But I still don't know how to pass the data to the android safely. And if those solutions which I thought are good because you need to decrypt it with android later. The best would be that it could be done without internet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with moodle, but I assume it is a web app? If so, the easiest way to handle the data securely would be:

1. Download the file from the web app over HTTPS
2. Use the Android Jetpack security libraries to store the file on the SD card

Here is an article (from the Google Android Security team) that shows how to generate keys and store encrypted files using Jetpack: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/data-encryption-on-android-with-jetpack-security-e4cb0b2d2a9

It abstracts away a lot of the crypto work for you.